# Google analytics in android app - how to track premium upgrade version?

Tags: android, google-analytics, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I followed this [Android tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/) and successfully added Google Analytics to my app.

It's all working great and I can see that it's automatically tracking the app version number.

My app also features a paid upgrade to premium so I'd like to the app versions to include this - e.g 1.0.1 lite or 1.0.1 premium - how can I do this?  Or is there a better way to track this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the EasyTracker [`ga_appVersion` parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/parameters). If for some reason, you can't do this, you can use [Custom Dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/customdimsmets)